# as3 - contact form not working

Tags: php, actionscript-3, flash

I know this question has been asked a couple of times,
but I cant make a contact form using as3 and php i always get an "UnidentifiedIndex"error ,here is the  code .
PHP:

```
<?php
{
$to = "name@yourdomain.com";
$subject = ($_POST['senderName']);
$message = ($_POST['senderMsg']);
$message .= "\n\n---------------------------\n";
$message .= "E-mail Sent From: " . $_POST['senderName'] . " <" . $_POST['senderEmail']  . ">\n";
$headers = "From: " . $_POST['senderName'] . " <" . $_POST['senderEmail'] . ">\n";
if(@mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers))
{
echo "answer=ok";
} 
else 
{
echo "answer=error";
}
}
?>
```

Action Script:

```
submit_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, sendMessage);
function sendMessage(e:MouseEvent):void
{
    var my_vars:URLVariables = new URLVariables();
    my_vars.senderName = name_txt.text;
    my_vars.senderEmail = email_txt.text;
    my_vars.senderMsg = message_txt.text;


var my_url:URLRequest = new URLRequest("mail.php");
my_url.method = URLRequestMethod.POST;
my_url.data = my_vars;

var my_loader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
my_loader.dataFormat = URLLoaderDataFormat.VARIABLES;
my_loader.load(my_url);

name_txt.text = "";
email_txt.text = "";
message_txt.text = "Message Sent";
```

}

By the way i am completely new to PHP

And this code i got it from a website so it is not mine 
and i am using xampp to create the server to open the php file 
can u help me?
And another question ,
Will this work on mobile if i keep the server running?
Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

This error means that the PHP script can't find the values in the $_POST object. Actionscript part looks good. Are you testing with all fields filled out or with empty fields?

It is always a good idea to catch up empty values in the script and set defaults, like

```
$senderName = isset($_POST['senderName']) ? $_POST['senderName'] : '';
```

First trace all variables in your my_vars to see what you are sending to the server. If that looks good, do a var_dump($_POST) in your PHP script to check what the script have received.

How do you intend to deploy it on the mobile? If it's an app, you might need a crossdomain.xml on your server. But theoretically - yes, you can make it work on mobile.

Comment: Thanks for your reply , I trace my_vars to see what i am sending to the server and it looked good but i dont understand the var_dump($POST)

Comment: i catched up empty values in script and the error still occurs

Comment: I wrote down var_dump($_POST) and it says array(size = 0)

Comment: Can you please tell me what i should change in my code because I really need this contact form

Comment: So this means your PHP script is not getting any values for some reason. Just to be sure - you do call the PHP script via Actionscript and not directly in the browser, right ? :) Does the script work if you put in on a web server (not local XAMPP but a real server somewhere) ?

Comment: Ok , how can i buy a web server ? can you please tell me a cheap web server for just a simple php doc and swf doc ?